# jQuery plugin:select only numerical data from a table

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, selector

I am creating a plugin that allows a user to select the table and and pops up a bar chart of the numerical data in the table(of one or two columns) on a webpage. I need to select only the numerical data so that I can store it in an array and pop up a bar chart . I am new to jQuery and I could not find any selector for td elements in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) tutorial. How can I achieve the above?  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE : Sample html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Demo </title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.hello-world.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id = "test" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>21</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>13</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "C:/Users/ayushi.jain/Desktop/js learn/mycode.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried popping a dialog box with only the numeric elements from the table. The code is such that as soon as the user selects the table, it pops up an alert with the selected text.

Here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PQbb7/97/

Comment: So you're looking for a selector that finds tds that only contain numbers?

Comment: yes something like that. right

Comment: There's this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/ but I'm not sure that will help. Can you show us any code?

Comment: I am starting to write it. Since I am a beginner, I first thought of learning all the possible options.

Comment: there is no selector to help, you will need to test the values yourself. Provide sample html if you want more help

Comment: ok let me update it thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [jQuery.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter `<td>` elements according to your requirement, in order to get only `<td>`s that contain numeric value you could use [jQuery.isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/) function, as:

```
var arr = [];
$('#test').find('td').filter(function () {
    //get only <td> that contain numeric value inside it
    return $.isNumeric( this.innerHTML );
}).each(function(i, val) {
    arr.push(val.innerHTML);
});
console.log(arr);
//gives --> ["21", "50", "13", "94"]
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcw4tg99/)

**Addition::**
If you cant use `jQuery.isNumeric`, you could use custom code to check for numeric value as:

```
$('#test').find('td').filter(function () {
    //get only <td> that contain numeric value inside it
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(this.innerHTML)) && isFinite(this.innerHTML);
}).each(function (i, val) {
    arr.push(val.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: It works separately. But when I am trying to integrate it with my code, it breaks.

Comment: @ayushi its works fine:: http://jsfiddle.net/PQbb7/98/ jQuery.isNumeric was added in jQuery version 1.7, so you need to use jQuery version >= 1.7

Comment: Oh i wasn't aware of the version discrepancy. Thank you so much :) :)

Comment: @ayushi i've added another answer that does not use jQuery.isNumeric you could use that as well

Comment: Thank you. could you tell me if one approach is better than the other in the above case? I am new and just want to grasp the concepts. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ayushi i think it doesnot matter, you can use whichever way you're comfortable with..but most important thing is you understand and know what you are doing..!